Laravel print auth user details
I have an API based application built with laravel and Vue JS in one project directory. I am using jwt auth system for login, this package: php-open-source-saver/jwt-auth
Now, I want to call this route from ajax request outside of my application :
http://127.0.0.1:3000/automation/get_data/sdfd

To do this I added this route in web.php file:
Route::get('/automation/get_data/{param1?}/{param2?}', [Automation::class, 'get_data']);

and the get_data method of Automation class is like this:
public function get_data ( Request $request ) {

    $user =  Auth::user();

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump( $user );
    echo '</pre>';

    echo 'get data method : access the data like this : <br/>';

    echo '<pre>';
        print_r($request->route('param1'));
        print_r($request->route('param2'));
    echo '</pre>';
}

Ajax request:
const accessToken = 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vMTI3LjAuMC4xOjgwMDAvYXBpL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNzE1ODM4OTQ1LCJleHAiOjE3MTU4NDI1NDUsIm5iZiI6MTcxNTgzODk0NSwianRpIjoiOVAzM0FvYVBDZjBKbjhzUiIsInN1YiI6IjEiLCJwcnYiOiIyM2JkNWM4OTQ5ZjYwMGFkYjM5ZTcwMWM0MDA4NzJkYjdhNTk3NmY3In0.Xx1bZXI808PKMzsKJFblY2WKSmDX2_ioC1oIvYjHaGo';
const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/automation/get_data/sdfd';
const headers = new Headers({
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
});

fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers,
    mode: 'no-cors'  // Add this line
})
.then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) { // Check for successful response status code
        throw new Error(`API request failed with status ${response.status}`);
    }
    return response.json(); // Convert to JSON
})
.then(data => {
    console.log("Received data from API:", data);
    // Access data properties here (e.g., data.user_id, data.message, etc.)
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error("Error:", error);
    // Handle errors based on error type (network, response status, etc.)
});

But I got no response, in console I can see:
index.html:33 Error: Error: API request failed with status 0
    at index.html:24:15

My overall goal is to call that route from outside of my application and show logged user details in the get_data method.
Could you please tell me how can I do this ?

Can you show what value has response inside .then(response => { block?

@Justinas here is the output : https://prnt.sc/F-ha73xFuSk2

Does this answer your question? Why fetch return a response with status = 0?

https://prnt.sc/zrO50iWVwXLr@Justinas now status = 0 is gone but I have this error:

So now you have to fix your CORS rule to include http://127.0.0.1:3000 in local environment: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/routing#cors

You will have to configure config/cors.php file to allow the necessary origins and methods:
return [
    'paths' => ['api/*', 'automation/*'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['http://127.0.0.1:3000'], // Add your specific origin here
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => false,
];

Ensure your route uses the JWT middleware to authenticate the request. Update your web.php file:
Route::middleware(['api', 'jwt.auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/automation/get_data/{param1?}/{param2?}', [Automation::class, 'get_data']);
});

Your Controller
public function get_data(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    return response()->json([
        'user' => $user,
        'param1' => $request->route('param1'),
        'param2' => $request->route('param2')
    ]);
}

Your Ajax
  <script>
        const accessToken = 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vMTI3LjAuMC4xOjgwMDAvYXBpL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNzE1ODM4OTQ1LCJleHAiOjE3MTU4NDI1NDUsIm5iOiIxNzE1ODM4OTQ1LCJqdGkiOiI5UDMzQW9hUENmMEpuOHNSIiwic3ViIjoiMSIsInBydiI6IjIzYmQ1Yzg5NDlmNjAwYWRiMzllNzAxYzQwMDg3MmRiN2E1OTc2ZjcifQ.Xx1bZXI808PKMzsKJFblY2WKSmDX2_ioC1oIvYjHaGo';
        const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/automation/get_data/sdfd';

        fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`API request failed with status ${response.status}`);
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log("Received data from API:", data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error:", error);
        });
    </script>


Thanks for your details anwer. Now the cors issus has gone. but I got - 401
UNAUTHORIZED error.

can you tell me which token I should pass to this ajax request?

When a user logs in , a valid JWT token is generated, which is what you need to supply in your AJAX call. Normally, after a successful login, your authentication controller generates and returns this token.

Yes, it working but in my application I already logged in. Now, I am sending this request from outside. is there any way I can show the already logged user details in the get_data method without passing the token to this Ajax request?
